# How to slice/split an array list in java based on a delimiter?

Tags: java, arrays, list, split, slice

I have a requirement where i have to split array list of strings to multiple smaller lists based on a delimiter. Lets say my list contains

```
["This list contains"],
["What I need"],
["bla bla"],
["bla bla"],
["bla bla"],
["bla bla"],
["Found"],
["some more"],
["irrelevant"],
["data"]
```

Whenever i find ***What I need***, i have to slice the list from that part till i find the string ***found***

so My resultant sublist should be of the form

```
["bla bla"],
["bla bla"],
["bla bla"],
["bla bla"]
```

Comment: The `List` interface has methods `indexOf` and `subList` that would be useful to you.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java;

Comment: Your notation is a little confusing to me. Is this an ArrayList of Arrays? Or a an ArrayList of Strings?

Comment: Hi @Scratte, Its an arraylist of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 9 or later, you can use the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API with the [`dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [`takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) methods:

```
    List<String> list = List.of(
            "This list contains",
            "What I need",
            "bla bla",
            "bla bla",
            "bla bla",
            "bla bla",
            "Found",
            "some more",
            "irrelevant",
            "data"
    );

    list.stream()
            .dropWhile(str -> !str.equals("What I need"))
            .skip(1) // to discard the start marker
            .takeWhile(str -> !str.equals("Found"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    
    /*
     * Output:
     * bla bla
     * bla bla
     * bla bla
     * bla bla
     */
```

This is assuming that the start and end markers only appear once in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

The search result will be within the "result" list, and the original array will be spliced.

```
String searchTermStart = "Andy", searchTermEnd = "Bill";
ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList(List.of("Eric", "Andy", "Joan", "Marc", "Bill", "Phil"));

boolean addToOther = false; 
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

Iterator<String> iterator = rows.iterator(); 

while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
    String row = iterator.next();  
    if (row.equals(searchTermStart)) {  
        result.add(row);
        iterator.remove();                
        addToOther = true;
    } else if (addToOther) { 
        result.add(row);
        if (row.equals(searchTermEnd)) {
            addToOther = false;
        }
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think use methods `string.split()`.

```java
String[] data = string.split(" ");
```